# Altair graphs show in VSCode but not on GitHub (default and mimetye)

Tags: python, github, altair

I have an altair graph that displays normally in VSCode, but doesn't show up when I push to GitHub.

I've tried adding `alt.renderers.enable("default")` and `alt.renderers.enable("mimetype")`. Mimetype changes things slightly - instead of seeing nothing, I get some kind of output, but it's just the message:

> <VegaLite 5 object>

> If you see this message, it means the renderer has not been properly enabled
> for the frontend that you are using. For more information, see
> https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#troubleshooting

Any idea how I could fix this? I've tried seaborn charts and they in both, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Altair charts rely on JavaScript for rendering, which GitHub's static notebook viewer doesn't execute. To display Altair charts on GitHub:

Use the 'mimetype' renderer in your Jupyter notebook with alt.renderers.enable('mimetype'). This works well for JupyterLab but not necessarily for GitHub.

Save the charts as images using chart.save('chart.png'). This requires Selenium and a WebDriver, but the resulting static images will display on GitHub.

Embed data within the notebook using alt.data_transformers.enable('json'). This ensures that the data for the charts is bundled with the notebook.

If these steps don't work, use Jupyter's nbviewer to host the notebook and link to it from your GitHub repository, as nbviewer can render interactive content. Alternatively, include static images of your charts in the repository and reference them in your README or notebook. Remember to mark your notebook as trusted in Jupyter to ensure the charts render before pushing to GitHub.